# iOS 10 Table view data are not fully displaying but fully displaying on iOS 9?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios10

A tableview with 58 cells, While i am trying to add 67 more cells to the tableview .
The tableview  is displaying only the first 11 cells.
Why this occurs?
This process is correctly working on iOS 9, but not in iOS 10.

Comment: Can you add the screen shots and code here?

Comment: There may b constraints issue. Please share screenshots.

Comment: Share your screen for proper understanding